# Why tmux always change my first window's name to bash after reloading

Tags: tmux

I have tmux-resurrect installed so I can save and reload windows. I have about 8 windows in 1 session. After save and reload. All windows' name are correct except the first one, it shows 0:bash-

How can I persist that window's name as well?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say, tmux-resurrect could be not restoring the name, or tmux could be changing it back. You could try turning off automatic-rename in tmux.conf, but the best bet might be to ask the tmux-resurrect authors.